# How to send the JWT token to the client with feathersjs-authentication?

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, token, feathersjs

I'm using **local authentication** in my **feathersjs REST-API** application, but after the user is authenticated, instead of sending me the **authentication token**, feathers is sending the following HTML as a response to the authentication request:

```
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="alongbase64string" alt="Feathers Logo">
    <main>
        <h1 class="center-text">Success</h1>
        <h3 class="center-text">You are now logged in. We've stored your JWT in a cookie with the name 
            <span class="italic">"feathers-jwt"</span> for you. It is:
        </h3>
        <pre id="token"></pre>
    </main>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

var token = getCookie('feathers-jwt');

var el = document.getElementById('token');
el.innerHTML = token;
</script>
```

which prints the following page:

[image]

I think this would work good enough if I was sending the request from a web page, but in my case I need to get the token, because **the client is a mobile app**, not a web browser, so cookies won't work for me.

Is it possible for me to make feathersjs send the token in the response? Something like:

```
{
    token: 'açldkjfaçldkfjçasdkfjdçakfjd'
}
```

This way I could store the token in the mobile app, and **use it to authenticate further requests** to my feathersjs API server.

For now I won't put any more code here, because the application was made entirely with the console commands available by feathersjs, like `feathers generate` but if anyone needs to understand more about the code, just let me know, and I will edit the question adding more details.

Comment: Assuming stock, and [according to the repo](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/blob/d4f341d81f094336a8bf8eec524f1305195844ee/src/middleware/index.js#L36), the token is in the headers (`req.headers['authorization']`). Have you tried a basic `res.send(token)` in place of the current `res.sendFile({authpage})` mechanic?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I couldn't find where is it sending me the file, or else I would send the token directly, it would be enought, already. Also, the link you passed me is validating the token sent by the client to the server, but I need the reverse of it, that is, I need to send the token from the server to the client.

Comment: [Here's where it's sending the auth-success file](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/blob/d4f341d81f094336a8bf8eec524f1305195844ee/src/index.js#L150)

Comment: Nice, @colonelsanders! Is there some way for me to change the behaviour so that instead of sending the file it sends the actual token? Editing this file is not an option, of course... But knowing this is the file already puts me in a better place to get to a solution. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure to set the `Accept` header in your request to `application/json` otherwise it'll assume HTML and send the page you are seeing.

Comment: Can't beleive I was missing just this. It works! Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind if I ask a related question? I would like to return just some of the fields of the user, not the full model properties. I thought this could be made by setting the `payload` array of the token authentication object, but it didn't work; every property keeps being sent to the client together with the token. I don't know if I did something wrong or if this is actually the way to do it.

Comment: It looks like `hooks` are the functionality I'm looking for. But I don't know how to add a hook to the `authentication` service. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, `auth/local` is just another service. You can add `before` and `after` hooks to `app.service('auth/local)`

Comment: Yes, got it working today afternoon. It's the first project I'm working on which uses feathersjs, so I'm learning a lot "on demand", but I like this framework and I'm enjoying this learning process very much. Thank you for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Use the local middleware instead of the socket scheme referenced in the question.

POST'ing login data to `/auth/local` will yield

```
{
  "token": {JWT},
  "data": {
    "email": "admin@feathersjs.com",
    "id": 0
  }
}
```

Your client can pull values from that JSON response and handle them appropriately.

Most anything beyond that will require modifying the stock Feathers demo.